# Input onChange() event is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

- I'm rendering an `Input` of `type='number'`.
- The **Input** has the value of `this.state.value`.
- The Input and all the UI Components are generated via **Semantic-UI**, but I think that's not of a significant importance info.
- I also have a **custom arrow menu** for this input instead of the original one. ***[input of type number has two arrows to decrease/increase the value]***

---

#### Render()

```
render() {
    // Custom Menu
    const arrowsMenu = (
    <Menu compact size='tiny'>
      <Menu.Item as='a' onClick={ this.decreaseNumber.bind(this) }>
        <Icon name='chevron left' size='small' />
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item as='a' onClick={ this.increaseNumber.bind(this) }>
        <Icon name='chevron right' size='small' />
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
    );

    return (
      <Input value={ this.state.value } type="number" label={ arrowsMenu } placeholder="Raplece ma" onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this) } />
      );
  }
```

---

**The Custom Menu uses these two functions:**

```
decreaseNumber(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value - 1
    });
  }

  increaseNumber(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1
    });
  }
```

---

#### onChange

You can place anything.

```
onChange(e) {
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log('Hello pals');
    console.log('====================================');
  }
```

---

### The problem is

That whenever I **push an Arrow** from the `Menu`, the `onChange()` event of the `Input` is **not triggered**. But the **value** of the **input** is **changed**.

(Of course, because the `this.state.value` variable is changed in the state)

If I do the same with the original arrows, of course, the value is changed as it should.

**Why is that and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Show full sample, where is onChange defined ?

Comment: As far as I know, `onChange()` is triggered by blurr, not by actual value/text change

Comment: onChange can have anything you want, it doesn't matter what its context is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `onChange` with any code you want, but if you want to reflect the new value you need to set the state according to the new input value from the event.
As for `decreaseNumber` and `increaseNumber` you need to change the state as well but here you are doing calculation so you need to make sure it's a number (or convert it to a number) because you are getting a string back from the event.

Working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    };
  }

  onChange = e => this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  increaseNumber = () => this.setState({value: Number(this.state.value) + 1});
  decreaseNumber = () => this.setState({ value: Number(this.state.value) - 1 });

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.decreaseNumber}>-</button>
        <input type="number" value={value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.increaseNumber}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit** 
For triggering the `onChange` handler just call `this.onChange` but note that you can't pass the event like the native event handler does but you can pass a simple object that mimic the normal `event` object with a `target.value`.
Another option is to try triggering it via a `ref` but keep in mind it can cause an infinite loop in some cases. 
Edited Example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    console.log('change', e.target.value);
  }
  increaseNumber = () => {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const nextValue = Number(value) + 1;
    const changeEvent = {
      target: {
        value: nextValue
      }
    };
    this.onChange(changeEvent);
  }

  decreaseNumber = () => {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const nextValue = Number(value) - 1;
     const changeEvent = {
      target: {
        value: nextValue
      }
    };
    this.onChange(changeEvent);
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.decreaseNumber}>-</button>
        <input type="number" value={value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <button onClick={this.increaseNumber}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit #2**
As a followup to your comment:

> list's value is its content/children. If some of the children change,
>   then list changes with them as well

Well, this has an easy solution, you can use the `ref` (like i mentioned in the first section of my answer) and dispatch an event with `bubbles:true` so it will bubble all the way up to the parents.
Using your new example code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 liOnChange(e) {
  console.log('listed item/items changed');
 }
  
  inputOnChange(e) {
   console.log('input changed');
  }
  handleClick(e){
    var event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
    this.myInput.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
 render() {
   return(
   <div>
       <ul>
         <li onChange={this.liOnChange.bind(this)}>
           <input ref={ref => this.myInput = ref} type='text'onChange={this.inputOnChange.bind(this)}/>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>+</button>
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I in general don't like using refs but sometimes you need them.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. The Number for Calculation, I don't think it's an object of importance in my case.

My problem is that onChange event is not triggered. Not that state doesn't change as it should. Don't know what your intentions were in your answers :/

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou i've updated my  answer with a new example, i hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Just one little change in your code. Is the `this.setState` in `increaseNumber`/`decreaseNumber` necessary? You pass the new value via `onChange` as `target` anyways.

Thanks, you really helped!

Comment: good catch! i will update my code. by the way, i recomment to not `bind` your handlers inside the `render` method as it will create a new instance of a function on each `render` call. this can set react's diffing algorithm oof track as it can reflect as a change between the virtual DOM tree and the real DOM and can lead to unnecessary DOM updates.

Comment: Hey @Sag1v now that I checked the code, I see that parent `<li onChange={}>` that contains the `input`  does not trigger `onChange` as it should. See the answer above, as @Brandon initially explains, triggering `onChange()` or changing the value programmatically is not the right way to change the input value. So, do you have anything in mind regarding the `<parent onChange>` elements which contains the input to be triggered when it changes? 

**Till then, I'm sorry I can't set your answer as a solution because it has this bug, which is gonna be serious for many people and for me as well.**

Comment: i'm not following, we are not triggering the native `onChange` here. we set a new state which is reflected in the input's `value`.  and what is the `<li>` you are referring to? i don't see it in your code.

Comment: It's not, but I think we should consider these things before making up a solution. I don't think we should use some code because it 'just works', this piece of code produces a bug. `<li>` is parent of `<input>`. Naturally, if `input.value` is changed then `input.onChanged` is triggered and `li.onChanged` event is triggered as well. But with this solution, `li.onChanged` event is not triggered.

Comment: why should `li` `onChange` be triggered? it's not an input and doesn't hold a `value` to be changed in the first place. is this something that semantic-ui does behind the scene?

Comment: Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/86790/
The list's content changes therefore the list's onChange event is triggered. To answer to you, list's `value` is its content/children. If some of the children change, then list changes with them as well.

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou got it, you want the event to be native and bubble up to the parents. see my **Edit #2** in the answer using refs and event dispatching.

Comment: Great. It's the answer people want. Although if I find a way to dispatch SyntheticEvents at Semantic-UI which I currently cannot, I will write my own answer as well. Yours will remain the Solution of the question though. Great job @Sag1v. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` is only called if the user goes into the Input component and interacts with it to change the value (e.g. if they type in a new value).  `onChange` is not called if you change the value programmatically through some other avenue (in your example changing it via the custom menu).

This is working as intended design.

If you want to trigger onChange, then call it from your `increaseNumber` and `decreaseNumber` methods.

Comment: That seems very reasonable thank you. But I was searching for some minutes now, how am I supposed to call these two functions via `ref`?

Tried this case `<Input ... ref={(input) => {this.input = input}}` and then in my `decreaseNumber()` tried this `this.input.increaseNumber()`. But apparently I didn't have access to that because such function doesn't exist there.

How will I access these two functions if I may ask? I just want to test your solution before I set my question as solved.